# C# XML CefSharp Menu-Handling

Tags: c#, menu, chromium, cefsharp

I'm make my first steps with an embedded browser in a C# Xaml environments.
The Chromium web browser is a nice and comfortable solution.

My question is how to show special menus:
I know that its possible to use Custom-MenuHandler. Thats ok.
But a concrete example is a Panel Menu of Grafana:

[image]

This menu is not visible in Chromium CefSharp component with C#.
How could I change this?

Thx in advance

Comment: So you're showing the Grafana interface using CefSharp, and those menus aren't rendering? You'll want to enable remote debugging (set `CefSettings.RemoteDebuggingPort = 1234`, then open `localhost:1234` in Chrome) and use the Chrome dev tools to try and spot any errors

Comment: Thx for the fast response: I have used this test project: 
https://github.com/cefsharptutorials/cefsharptutorials/tree/master/CefSharpTutorials/RemoteDebugging

The behavior is the same If I try to activate the panel menu from the leftBrowser. In the rightBrowser the menu appears, but with the following message: "Failed to load resource: :3000/api/ds/query:1 the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)"

Comment: The https://github.com/cefsharptutorials/cefsharptutorials repository is years out of date, uses an ancient version of the browser. They're unofficial examples created by someone else. For testing purposes you can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample which is kept up to date. To open DevTools for debugging see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Comment: I have used from the https://github.com/cefsharptutorials/cefsharptutorials/tree/master/CefSharpTutorials/RemoteDebugging
only the source code.
CefShart.Wpf V89.0.170 is the packet version which is installed with nuget.